# RedactorClips and RedactorStyles plugins not working

Tags: richtext, redactor

I have both Redactor Clips and Redactor Styles plugins installed, but neither seem to affect my rich text editor (i.e., i don't see any extra buttons). Are there known issues?

Comment: I have does not work, i add button in json, but she not show, I updated craft cms and earn

Comment: You updated Craft to 2.3.2620 (latest version) and now it works?

Comment: yes, craft 2.3.2620

Comment: I write in json replaceDivs: false, but when I insert the clip div tags are cut

Answer (score 1):

Did you [add the buttons](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/#set-buttons) to your toolbar by editing or adding a config file:
`/craft/config/redactor/my_custom_toolbar.json`?

You can configure multiple redactor setting files and apply them individually to your rich text fields from the [field settings](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/#set-buttons).

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out. I had to add entries to the 'plugins' setting in the redactor tool bar json:

plugins: ['fullscreen', 'clips', 'styles']

Now they're showing up

joe