# Redactor Styles Plugin stopped working

Tags: redactor, plugin-redactorstyles

The very useful [Redactor Styles plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/RedactorStyles-Craft) has stopped working for me. I have the little wand in the toolbar, and appropriately styled entries in the drop down, but clicking on them does nothing.
[image: toolbar with dropdown]

Styles JSON Object:

```
[
  {
    "btnName": "Button Link",
    "className": "redactor_format_button",
    "spanClass": "button_link"
  },
  {
    "btnName": "air",
    "className": "redactor_format_air",
    "spanClass": "air"
  },
  {
    "btnName": "water",
    "className": "redactor_format_water",
    "spanClass": "water"
  }
]
```

Redactor config file:

```
{
  /* docs say 'json', but really we are allowed basic javascript object */
  /* allowedTags: need inline for RedactorStyles */
  allowedTags: ['a', 'blockquote', 'br', 'div', 'dl', 'dt', 'dd', 'em', 'h2', 'h3', 'hr', 'i', 'iframe', 'img', 'inline', 'li', 'ol', 'option', 'p', 'select', 'span', 'strong', 'ul', 'video'],
  formattingTags: ['p', 'blockquote', 'h2', 'h3'],
  buttons: ['html','|','formatting','|','bold','italic','|','unorderedlist','orderedlist','|','link','image','video', '|', 'horizontalrule'],
  plugins: ['fullscreen', 'styles', 'pagebreak', 'clips'],
  stylesJson: RedactorStyles.stylesJson
}
```

The field is using that configuration, and neither `Clean up HTML?` nor `Purify HTML?` is checked. This used to work, and I don't think I've changed anything (famous last words...)

Comment: Any JS errors in your browser's console?

Comment: No JS errors unfortunately

Comment: Beats me... I can't even get the wand icon to show up. :(

Comment: @BradBell wand icon: [this](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/redactorclips-and-redactorstyles-plugins-not-working?rq=1) question...

Comment: Seems like all my redactor plugins has stopped working. I'll look into it.

Comment: I spoke too soon, my bad, they should work. Except, setting inline styles with Redactor Styles is broken. There's something fishy going on, span's are created inside redactor, but removed somewhere along the way.  I have to debug some more to see if I can find a fix for it. Marion, are the styles you've set up inline styles? If not, could you update your question with the stylesJSON code (from the plugin settings page)?

Comment: @AndréElvan I think they're inline? Added the stylesJSON to the question